# PHP POST print check box entries: nothing I have found on forums works

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I have scoured the forums - here and elsewhere - trying to find a way to print out the checked options from a POST form that uses a check box group with the name `areas[]` where VALUE starts at`1` and goes on for another 6 options. So in each case NAME is `areas[]` but VALUE goes from 1 to 6.

(All the other entries from this form - such as Name, Tel number, etc. - are carried over without any problems.)

At best, when I try (to take one example of what I've tried)

```
$arr = $_POST[areas]
```

then try to for each over the array, the word "Array" is printed. Great.

If I try 
    `$_POST['areas']` I get a server error. A lot of things I've found on forums result in a server error.

I've tried all the obvious things - looping with `for` instead of `for each` ... at best I get `Array` or, weirder, `A`. I always choose 3 options in my tests.

I'm using PHP 5.3.8.

Can anyone suggest something that might work?

Comment: Instead of describing what you've tried, it might help if you actually gave us a sample of code:  Both the HTML and the PHP that's trying to interpret it.

Comment: According from what you said, you use 'areas[]' so that seems normal that $_POST[areas] returns an array. var_dump( $_POST); will show you everything that you posted, you might be able to find what you are looking for in it...

Comment: Second @WolfmanJoe, could you post some snippets of code which represent the functionality that isn't working for you, preferably working self-contained

Comment: @user2190704 - if `var_dump` was useful, but you still aren't sure how to use it, that's progress!  Copy / paste the HTML holding the checkboxes and the `var_dump` output into your original post, so we can see what you're working with.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to check for each checkbox you display if its value is in the $_POST['areas'] :

```
$areas = $_POST['areas']; // if you get an error here, check your code cause it must work
//Some code...
$checked = '';
if (in_array($value, $areas)){
    $checked = 'checked="CHECKED"';
}
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="areas[]" '.$checked.' value="'.$value.'"/>';
```

Comment: Thanks, guys. the var_dump($_POST) was helpful, and showed that my values are being posted, but I'm getting nowhere accessing them.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is most likely related to the way html returns values of checkboxes.

if a checkbox is checked-in it's value is returned, if it isn't checked-in no value whatsoever is returned.

In a case you would be picking colours from checkboxes called `name='colours[]'` your values will be like this: (fist line is choices, second the returned array in php)

```
[x] red  [ ] green  [ ] blue  [x] yellow  [ ] black  [ ] white

    array('red','yellow')

[ ] red  [ ] green  [ ] blue  [x] yellow  [ ] black  [x] white

    array('yellow','white')

[ ] red  [ ] green  [ ] blue  [ ] yellow  [ ] black  [ ] white

    null (no array returned)
```

one way of doing it is using different name for each option and check for your values in this style:

```
$red = isset($_POST['ck_red']);
$green = isset($_POST['ck_green']);
...
```

That of course in case you defined your red check box as `name='ck_red'` etc.

**EDIT**
(Your code follows)

html:

```
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="areas[]" VALUE="1">The Homeless</INPUT><BR />
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="areas[]" VALUE="2">The Elderly</INPUT><BR />
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="areas[]" VALUE="3">Refugees</INPUT><BR />
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="areas[]" VALUE="4">The handicapped</INPUT><BR />
```

php:

```
$areas[] = "$_POST[areas]"; 
foreach ($areas as $value) { 
    echo $value . " "; 
}
```

**Answer**: You have an error is in the assignment `$areas[] = "$_POST[areas]";` and namely in using the `"` around the `$_POST[areas]` - by doing so you are telling the parser, that you want to know the textual value of variable $_POST[areas] which is an array and php's way of dealing with it is to return TEXT **'array'** instead of (as for example in javascript) the list of elements delimited by coma. The other error is, eventhough it would work as you have it, that you are reffering to undefined constant `areas` instead of to string literal `'areas'` as in `$_POST['areas']` (notice the single quotes `'` around the key name. The last mistake is assigning the `$_POST['areas']` to `$areas[]` instead of `$areas` (without the `[]`). What you are doing there is you are adding a new element of array to array (areas) to which you are assigning the value of `$_POST['areas']` so in case it was without the first error (the `"`) it would create two dimensional array `areas => array(array('a','b','c'))`

Fix (php):

```
$areas = $_POST['areas'];
foreach ($areas as $value) { 
    echo $value . " "; 
}
```

Comment: My form code is:
    <INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="areas[]" VALUE="1">The Homeless</INPUT><BR />
    <INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="areas[]" VALUE="2">The Elderly</INPUT><BR />
    <INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="areas[]" VALUE="3">Refugees</INPUT><BR />
    <INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="areas[]" VALUE="4">The handicapped</INPUT><BR />
ETC.

and my code is:
    $areas[] = "$_POST[areas]";
foreach ($areas as $value)
{
 echo $value . " ";
}

Result: Array.

Sorry, haven't got the hang of formatting yet.

Comment: @user2190704 it's not possible to format in comments. however, depending on what are you doing with it in php chose Marshall's or my answer. What i tried to tell you with my answer, is that using array for group of checkboxes may not be best option, but it depends on how you process the input (in php) afterwards. Now i noticed an error in what you posted, so i'm going to update my answer and include that in there.

Comment: oh boy (hits forehead with palm) - thanks so much. this is a classic case of copying the syntax of all the other variable assignments, without thinking how it works. thanks a million to all who answered.

Comment: @user2190704 :) it happens. no problem :)